# $ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\sin x}~dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I integrate this ?
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\sin{x}}~dx $$
I have tried using dominating convergence theorem to evaluate this to $0$ . Is there any other way to evaluate this integral ?

Thank you.

Comment: does the even converge?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the minus

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: I don't think the minus changes anything really

Comment: that integral does not converge. $e^{-\sin(x)} > 0$ on $[0,\infty)$ and periodic.

Comment: One even has $e^{-\sin x}\geq e^{-1}$ on $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: [A graphical interpretation here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%5B-sin%5Bx%5D%5D) will show that the area under the function is always positive and not decreasing.

Comment: Sorry I will edit the post

Comment: If the Edit is the "real" question, you should probably delete this question and open a new one. As it stands, this question is confusing: the title asks one thing, the first question asks about something else and the edited part asks about a *third* thing.

Comment: Your last edit could just be a **new question**, this would be respectful for those who answered the OP.

Comment: that's right l'll not delete the question.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\exp(\pm~\sin x)~dx ~=~ \int_0^\tfrac\pi2\exp(\pm~\cos x)~dx ~=~ \frac\pi2~\Big[I_0(1)~\pm~L_0(1)\Big],~$ where $I$ and $L$ represent the [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and the [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) function, respectively.

Answer (score 8):

This integral doesn't converge. Since the integrand is periodic with period $2\pi$, we have that
$$\int_0^{2\pi n}e^{-\sin(x)} dx = n\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\sin(x)}dx := n\cdot I$$
where $n$ is a natural number. Since the function $e^{-\sin(x)}$ is positive everywhere, $I$ is positive, and so as $n\to\infty$ the above goes to infinity, and so the integral does not converge.

Answer (score 6):

One may observe that
$$
e^{-\sin{x}} \ge e^{-1},\qquad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$ yielding, by comparison, the **divergence** of the given integral:
$$
\int_0^M e^{-\sin{x}}\:dx \ge \int_0^M e^{-1}\:dx.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that both sine and its exponential are periodic and since exponential is non-negative everywhere, the integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : $$\forall x\in[0,\infty),|e^{-\sin{x}}| \geq|e^{-1}|$$

Comment: I think you mean $\geq$

Answer (score 1):

Because $e^{-\sin(x)} \geq e^{-1}$, one has

$$
\liminf_{a \to +\infty} \int_0^a e^{-\sin(x)} dx\geq \liminf_{a \to +\infty} \int_0^a e^{-1}dx = \liminf_{a \to +\infty} ae^{-1} = +\infty
$$
whereby
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\sin(x)}dx = \infty .
$$